# How should I follow-up my question when seeking further explanation?

Tags: discussion, support

I [asked a question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/3040/10) that I was completely in the dark on. I got good answers, and now I know the meaning of the word and why it is used. However, I still don't grasp *how* it is used. Is it appropriate to ask for a diagram or some drawings explaining how it is used in different stages of woodworking? For example when the thing is in open and closed state, and where to place it?

Answer (score 3):

Why and how are different questions.  So I think it is reasonable to ask a follow on question.  Make sure you are clear on what you are looking for and how the question differs from the other one, can even have a link in the new question pointing to the old one to help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular question, to be honest I'd head to [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

The word you are asking about, as explained in answers to your question, is simply [a word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/camber), just like "curve" and "arch" and "red" and "sharp" are words. It means exactly what its definition says, it's used exactly as its definition implies, and you use it in any context where it is appropriate to use that word. If something has a camber then that something has a camber. That's it. This site is not the right site for asking things like "Can you give me an example of something with a curve in it?"

Nothing more can really be said about it and at this point I think it is a language issue. Example usages can be found in the dictionary link. The word itself is not specific to woodworking.

If you are asking about camber in something specific, and that something has to do with woodworking, you can always post a new, clear question here. The other reason nothing more could be said about "camber" is that you were specifically asked to provide more context there and you did not, so you will also have to work on ways to formulate questions more clearly, remembering that **nobody here is looking over your shoulder reading what you are reading and seeing what you are seeing, and we have no way of knowing what you are looking at unless you tell us.**

"I'm reading about extendable tables, what is 'camber'?" is not enough for anything more than a link to a dictionary definition of "camber".

If you are asking something specifically about table slides then you need to be clear about exactly what you are asking. A camber in a table slide is exactly what it says: A camber (a curve) in a table slide. So it's a table slide with a camber. A table slide with a curve in it. Get it? If you want to know something more about the shape of a particular table slide then be clear. We couldn't tell what you were asking there because you were unclear: For all we knew you were talking about a camber in the table, in its legs, in one piece of wood, in your tools, we had to take wild guesses at what curved thing you had in mind, with our only hint being that this mysterious cambered object you were asking about was somehow related to tables.

Comment: I did just that. I'm new here, getting to know that I have to write less words with more essence. Strict, ordered, well written.

Comment: @Nachmen Don't worry about the "less words" part for now. Focus on the "more essence". Too many words won't hurt, too little essence will. "Less words" can wait. Editors can subtract extra words, but they can't add missing essence.